# MSN Messenger "what I'm listening to" API from .NET

Tags: .net, msn-messenger

Is there a way to modify the 'what's playing' functionality on MSN messenger through a .NET class library or application?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting your code to [A] interact with a locally running instance of the Live Messenger client (i.e., get the "what's playing" from the running Live Messenger client, or send it the name of a new song to update its status with), or [B] get/set your "what's playing" status independently of the Live Messenger client -- i.e., without it needing to be installed or running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079432/windows-live-messenger-what-im-listening-to-function